# How to check if filename is having characters other than [a-z][A-Z][0-9]-_#.!@ in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I get filenames from couple of folders and then I have to check if incoming filename is valid or not. 
I have to allow just these characters (Alphabets Numerics - _ # . ! @) that could come in any sequence.

I have a PowerShell script where I am getting filenames to process, but before processing I need to check if filename is containing just these (above) characters otherwise I would log a message on console saying "Filename is invalid."

```
$Regex = <Need this>
$clientFiles = Get-ChildItem $path | Select-Object FullName, Name, CreationTime 
foreach($cFile in $clientFiles){    
    if ($cFile."Name" -match $Regex){
        #Further process
    }
    else{
        #Dont want to process and will log message here
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post your script.

Comment: Look at Regular Expressions. Write some code then edit this question with specific problems that you are having with the code that you write.

Comment: Hint: the regex `[^b]+` is used to check if a string contains something other than `b`

Comment: Also, this might help you in the future:

https://regexr.com/

And a handy desktop app called Expresso:

http://www.ultrapico.com/expressodownload.htm

Answer (score 3):

To check if the string input does not match the following string [a-z][A-Z][0-9]-_#.!@ use the regular expression `[^-a-zA-Z0-9_#.!@]+`.

Point to note : Inside character class always put - first, otherwise - is treated as metacharacter inside character class. `^` negates the contents of the character class.

If the file name is the only string in the line then use `^[^-a-zA-Z0-9_#.!@]+$`.
^ and $ add's line boundary to the regex.

```
$regex = "[^-a-zA-Z0-9_#.!@]+"
$fileName = "invalidData++"
If($fileName -match $regex){echo "Invalid File name '$fileName'"}
```

Comment: Good to know Abishek, I'm not a regex expert, so these can be tricky!

Comment: as I would only have 1 line a string, i can remove '+' from the end?

Comment: + is used to match 1 or more character. If you remove + then it matchs only one character from the given string.

Comment: Simplified: `[^\w#.!@\-]+`

Answer (score 0):

This returns all as True

```
$reg = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\#\\.\\!\\_]"
$test1 = "a9z!"
$test2 = "@.!"
$test3 = "r0YUH#"

$test1 -match $reg
$test2 -match $reg
$test3 -match $reg
```

Comment: I have a filename "20171010_12345678_10193_upd_20171009,msrf.xml" and this filename is being matched and giving me "True" i.e. $reg = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\#\\.\\!\\_]"
$test1 = "20171010_12345678_10193_upd_20171009,msrf.xml"
$test1 -match $reg. this filename is having comma in it and i want regex to give "False"